# Outlook 2013 assigned task is received as email with untitled attachment

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, tasks

My manager is assigning me tasks through Outlook, but I receive them as emails with unrecognized attachments rather than tasks that I can accept or reject.

[image: Task Email]

I am using Outlook 2013, but she has an older version - I think Outlook 2010. Is this a compatibility problem?

NB. She is able to send me meeting requests and my Outlook recognizes those no problem - I can send back an accepted/reject response.

[image]

Comment: What type of account do you and your manager use (Exchange/POP3/...)?

Comment: We use MS Exchange

Comment: This may be relevant: http://www.slipstick.com/outlook/tasks/cant-accept-or-decline-tasks/ - See if you can send your manager a task and if they can accept or decline. Seems to be a bug in Outlook 2010 with regard to IMAP and Tasks. If you're both on the same network, a workaround you can try to is to right-click on Task and either share tasks or add you as an editor to the specific Task folder.